# What Is Possible Use One Reference Field To Multiple Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I want to make 3 Tables like this :

**wc_groups Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wc_groups` (
  `id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idgroup` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `content` text,
  `status` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idgroup` (`idgroup`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**wc_matches Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wc_matches` (
  `id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` date NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `place` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `team_id_1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `team_id_2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `edituser` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `group_id_foreign` (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**wc_teams Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wc_teams` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `wc_teams`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `group_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `wc_groups` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Why i got an error when execution Code to create table `wc_team` ?

What's possible to use What Is Possible Use One Reference Field ( `wc_groups` (`id`) ) To Multiple Foreign Key Constraint ?

Comment: I want to mae a structure like this

**wc_matches.group_id->wc_groups.id

wc_teams.group_id->wc_groups.id**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean with multiple foreign keys.

But the problem in your wc_teams create query is that you have a lost , behind

```
 `group_id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

But you also miss your primary key so i guess you need this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wc_teams` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: I want to mae a structure like this

**wc_matches.group_id->wc_groups.id

wc_teams.group_id->wc_groups.id**

Comment: @user3395037 i see you accepted the answer so i guess everything works now? Because the problem was not 2 foreign keys but that your wc_teams table was never created